# SQL Variable Column Name depends on Row data

Tags: sql-server-2005, dynamic-sql

I am tryin to get a column from DB that returns Variable Column Name which depends on Row data. I know I can have variable Column name with using Dynamic SQL, but what if the name actually depends on the row's information.

```
SELECT name,age FROM dbo.Names
```

--Reurns 'name' as column name

```
SELECT name as [xyz],age FROM dbo.Names
```

--Returns 'xyz' as column name

```
EXEC 'SELECT name as [' +  @var + '], age FROM dbo.Names'
```

--Returns @var value as Column name

```
SELECT name AS ['Hi: ' + age ] FROM dbo.Name ?????
```

--So I am trying to get 'Hi: 25' or 'Hi: 40' as column name

How would I do that?  Any help please?

Comment: you should provide examples of the data and the expected column names

Comment: Putting to one side my doubts about whether this is a good idea, presumably there can be only one value as a column can't have different names depending on the row so can't you retrieve it and use your approach three?

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the approaches for one line, but not for selecting all rows:

```
DECLARE @age INT
SET @age = SELECT TOP 1 @age FROM dbo.NAMES
EXEC 'SELECT name as [Hi ' +  @age + '], age FROM dbo.Names'
```

Why do you need to do this in SQL and not in application logic?

Comment: +! suggesting this is in the wrong piece of logic.  It probably is just a formatting issue on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna have to change on Application Side. I don't think that's possible to change in the SQL Side. That logic only works for the 1 row, I need multiple rows.